# Facebook PHP SDK logout issue

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, session-cookies

So, I *am* aware that the issue has been raised a number of times. But most of the questions are old and after browsing for at least one hour, I have yet to find a good answer to this issue.

I am using the official Facebook PHP SDK for my website. My application lets the users log in and out. Problem is, you can't really log out. The only way to get back to the login page is to clear the cookies manually. This is just such a basic issue, surely there must be an easy solution?

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$me = $facebook->api('/me');

if ($me) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
```

Comment: Did you try using 'try' and 'catch' instead? This is how it should be done structurally, not using if($me): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: Yes. I even copied that whole segment, and their own logout function doesn't even work.

Comment: What did you see when you click on the logout hyperlink with href="<?= $logoutUrl ?>" ?

Comment: I just end up on the same page. But the link goes to facebook.com/logout.php?next= etc.

Comment: And how do u know/detect that the user is not logged out after that? Are you using if($facebook->getUser()) or are you using try and catch with $facebook->api('/me'); inside the try statement? Annoyingly getUser() will still return the user's id even when already logged out.

Answer (score 6):

```
$facebook -> destroySession();
```

works for me.

As well as manually clearing the fbsr_ cookie

```
setcookie("fbsr_YOUR_APP_ID",'',time()-10);
```